# Not able to set default selection for <select> element in angular js

Tags: html, angularjs

To illustrate the problem, I have created two HTML snippets for comparison. The first one sets the default selection for select element to 'One' as expected.

```js
(function(angular) {
  angular.module('m', [])
    .run(function($rootScope) {
      $rootScope.x = {
        val: "1"
      };
    });
})(window.angular);
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="m">
  <select ng-model="x.val">
    <option value="0">Zero</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
  </select>
  {{ x }}
</body>

</html>
```

I do not want to hardcode all the options into the HTML, since they can change in future. I am trying to use ng-repeat, but seeing the default selection is always set to 'Zero'. Can someone explain the reason why it is not working, and how to fix it?

```js
(function(angular) {
  angular.module('m', [])
    .run(function($rootScope) {
      $rootScope.nums = ["Zero", "One", "Two"];
      $rootScope.x = {
        val: "1"
      };
    });
})(window.angular);
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="m">
  <select ng-model="x.val">
    <option ng-repeat="num in nums" value="{{ $index }}">{{ num }}</option>
  </select>
  {{ x }}
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Use ng-options with array of objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the correct `ngOptions` syntax should fix the problem:

```js
(function(angular) {
  angular.module('m', [])
    .run(function($rootScope) {
      $rootScope.nums = ["Zero", "One", "Two"];
      $rootScope.x = {
        val: "One"
      };
    });
})(window.angular);
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="m">
  <select ng-model="x.val" ng-options="num as num for num in nums"></select><br /> 
  selected value: {{ x.val }}
</div>
```

Comment: I need `selected value: 1` instead of `selected value: One`. Is it possible without converting the array into object?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution.

```js
(function(angular) {
  angular.module('m', [])
    .run(function($rootScope) {
      $rootScope.nums = ["Zero", "One", "Two"];
      $rootScope.x = $rootScope.nums[1]; // Index position of One
    });
})(window.angular);
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="m">
  <select ng-model="x" ng-options="num as num for num in nums"></select><br /> 
  selected value: {{ x }}
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is to set the model (x in your case) to index of selected element within array instead of array content. With your solution, I would be able to set initial value but then will require another operation to get back the index. Thanks anyway :)